# HTTP redirect specific URL to a specific location

Tags: iis, redirect, http-redirect

I want to receive requests to my server, check the received URL and forward it to a specific path into my server. For example:

- If I receive, for example, docs.mydomain.com, I want to do something into IIS and forward it to wwwroot/docs;
- If I receive, for example, photos.mydomain.com, I want to do something into IIS and forward it to wwwroot/photos.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes This is certainly possible using [IIS URL Rewrite Module.](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)and using some regex pattern matching.

[How to use url redirect module.](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

so in your case you will want to match just /docs with ^(/docs)(/.*)?

then redirect to

/photos{R:2}